# How do I have Primefaces focus not move to first field and yet show validation

Tags: validation, primefaces, focus

I want to use <p:focus> in two ways:
1. Move to the input field if that field fails validation, i.e. is required
2. If on a page that has an input field that is visible when the page loads then move to that field. But if the page has a lot of introduction text and the input field is way down the page then don't move to the field as the user has to then scroll up to read the start of the page.

How can I have both cases handled? It seems that if I have <p:focus> I cannot avoid the page scrolling automatically way down the page if the first input field is there but I also want to move to the required field if a value has not been given.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For 1: See the answer above or http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/focus.xhtml

For 2: The only solution I know of that can achieve this is to *not* use the `<p:focus/>` and implement your own focus code (not to difficult). Detect the position of the first input and if it is far down, don't 'focus' it.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use the attribut for to select the default focused element. 
Second, you only have to update your p:focus, and it will automatically select the first field where error occured.

Comment: Hi Bigmwaj, sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you please explain for me a bit more?

Comment: @Novarse: Bigmwaj is right regarding the selection of the first invalid field. Check http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/focus.xhtml. Regarding the 'not scroll down if to far below', my answer below is still valid

Comment: What I wanted to tell you is to not use de "for" attribut of p:focus component and try only to update the p:focus component evertime you trigger the form submit button.

Comment: Hi guys, I only have <p:focus /> on my page so I don't use the "for" attribute. How do I "update" the <p:focus/> ? Sorry if I'm missing the obvious.

Comment: You can do twe things:
- Update the whole form that contains your p:focus

Comment: Or give an Id to your p:focus an use it to your p:commandButton to get it updated when it's get clicked.